# .toFixed function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, methods, jestjs

I am trying to get the method .toFixed into a function and use this function in the return with $(Fixed).

The reason I want it in a function is because it makes it easier for me to test it with jest to see if the function works. I'm going to put the function in a separate component so I can call it anywhere.

I have searched for how to get the.toFixed into a function in JavaScript and it would be as follows:

```
function financial(x) {
  return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
}
```

However, in my example I wouldn't know what to enter at 'x', so I removed parseFloat(x).

My code looks like this.

```
function Nutrients({mealsData}) {
    const nutrients = mealsData.nutrients;

    function Fixed(){
        return Number.toFixed(2);
    }

    return (
        <main className={styles.main}>
            <section className={styles.meals}>
                {mealsData.meals.map((meal) => {
                    return <Food key={meal.id} meal={meal}/>
                })}
            </section>

            <section className={styles.nutrients}>
                <h1 className={styles.h1}>The four main nutrients in these dishes</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li className={styles.tooltip}>Calories: {nutrients.calories.$(Fixed)}
                    </li>                    
                </ul>
            </section>
        </main>
    );
}

export default Nutrients;
```

I get the error message 'TypeError: nutrients.calories.$ is not a function'.

Comment: What is `$` in your code snippet? Seems the error is saying that `&` isn't a property on `nutrients.calories` to access or call as a function. Why not `Number(nutrients.calories).toFixed(2)` instead?

Comment: I learned in JavaScript that if you want to call a function that you do so with $(function name) does it, so I expect this is also possible in React?

I want to put this method into a function so I can more easily test it with jest to see if the function works.

Comment: "I learned in JavaScript that if you want to call a function that you do so with $(function name) does it, so I expect this is also possible in React?" -- that is incorrect. Functions are most simply called with double parens like so: `functionName()`

Comment: That would be news to me, and I don't believe it. Were you previously using `jQuery`? `jQuery` uses a `$` generally as a function as a stand-in for `document.getElementById`.

Comment: No I was just taught basic vanilla JavaScript. And now that I look back on some projects this was indeed used in combination with document.getElementById. I still have a lot to learn...

Comment: It's not going to be easier to test, because that function is only accessible _inside_ `Nutrients`. Test the _behaviour_ - given known `mealsData`, is the text content of the `li` formatted appropriately? Then you can refactor where, how and even _whether_ you call `.toFixed` to your heart's content and be confident that the code works overall.

Comment: I put the function in a separate component so I can call it anywhere and that way I can also test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if u want to use `Fixed`

```js
function toFixed(num) {
  return num?.toFixed(2)
}

<li className={styles.tooltip}>Calories: {Fixed(nutrients?.calories)}</li>
```

or u don't need `Fixed`.

```js
<li className={styles.tooltip}>Calories: {nutrients?.calories?.toFixed(2)}</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works, but I want to put this method in a function so I can test it more easily with jest whether the function works.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I hope to come up with this kind of code from myself someday. Thanks so much!